# Fill a Rectangle inside a Grid

Tags: c#, wpf, grid, rectangles, stackpanel

I have created a Grid in WPF with rectangles inside, and the XAML is the following one:

```
<Grid HorizontalAlignment="Left" Name="grid1" VerticalAlignment="Top" Initialized="grid1_Initialized">
    <Rectangle Height="300" HorizontalAlignment="Left" Margin="228,120,0,0" Name="stackPanel1" VerticalAlignment="Top" Width="40" Fill="Red" />
    <Rectangle Fill="OrangeRed" Height="300" HorizontalAlignment="Left" Margin="268,120,0,0" Name="stackPanel2" VerticalAlignment="Top" Width="40" />
    <Rectangle Fill="Orange" Height="300" HorizontalAlignment="Left" Margin="308,120,0,0" Name="stackPanel3" VerticalAlignment="Top" Width="40" />
    ...
</Grid>
```

(Just ignore the names stackPanel1, stackPanel2, ..., they're now rectangles).

What I want to do is to assign a Fill color, but I can't get access to them. What I have tried is:

```
foreach (var stackpanl in mainGrid.Children.OfType<StackPanel>())
{
     int row = Grid.GetRow(rectangle);

     if (Grid.GetRow(stackpanl) < 2)
     {
          stackpanl.Background = new SolidColorBrush(Colors.Blue);                    
     }
}
```

But this returns a value of 0 for row at each iteration.

I have also tried:

```
for(int i = 0; i < 15 ; i++)
        {
            var rectangle = grid1.Children[i];
            int row = Grid.GetRow(rectangle);
            if (row == 2)
            {
                rectangle.Fill = new SolidColorBrush(Colors.Magenta);
            }
        }
```

But apparently Fill is not a property regarding a grid1.Children[i] element.

How can I change the color of the individual rectangles? Thanks!

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Fill is a property of Rectangle. You have already given names to Rectangles. Cast the returned child to Rectangle.

eg;

```
Rectangle r = new Rectangle();
r.Fill = new SolidColorBrush(Colors.BlanchedAlmond);
```

//

```
Rectangle rectangle = (Rectangle)grid1.Children[i];
rectangle.Fill = new SolidColorBrush(Colors.Magenta);
```